# O que acontece em uma conversão de um char para um int?

Tags: c, conversão-de-tipo, int, char

Como funciona quando se pega uma variável e faz `char-48` para transformar em inteiro, como por exemplo nesse código que eu fiz, utilizei uma data por exemplo "22/05/1994" armazenada em um vetor de char e transformei em dia, mês e ano todos em valor de inteiro. O fato acontece na linha 5 na expressão `num[j]=data[i]-48`. O que acontece nesta operação para acontecer a conversão?

```
void transformarDataEmInt(char *data, int *dia, int *mes, int *ano){
    int i,j=0;
    int num[8];
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        num[j]=data[i]-48;
        if (i==2||i==5){
            continue;
        }
        j++;
    }
    *dia = num[0]*10 + num[1];
    *mes = num[2]*10 + num[3];
    *ano = num[4]*1000 + num[5]*100 + num[6]*10 + num[7];
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O que ocorre é que o tipo `char` em linguagens como o C são na verdade tipos inteiros. No [artigo da Wikipedia sobre os tipos da linguagem C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) esta é a descrição do tipo `char`:

> char -> smallest addressable unit of the machine that can contain
>   basic character set. It is an integer type. Actual type can be either
>   signed or unsigned depending on the implementation.

Ou seja, trata-se da menor unidade endereçável pela máquina capaz de conter o conjunto de caracteres. Esse conjunto de caracteres foi padronizado pelo [ANSI](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) sendo chamado de [Tabela ASCII](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (acrônimo para *American Standard Code for Information Interchange*).

Dessa forma, quando você tem um `char` ele armazena na verdade o valor decimal que representa um caractere nessa tabela. Se você consultar o link da tabela que eu referenciei, verá que o valor 48 é utilizado para representar o dígito* zero (`'0'`).

A sacada de utilizar a operação aritimética de subtração é simplesmente converter facilmente o caractere no valor representativo do dígito (isto é, converter o caractere `'3'`, por exemplo, no valor 3).

Supondo então:

```c
char c = '3';
int i = c - 48;
printf("O valor de i é [%d]\n", i);
```

Produz o resultado:

```
O valor de i é [3]
```

Pois, como segundo a tabela ASCII `c = '3' = 51`, tem-se que `c - 48 = 51 - 48 = 3`.

* Nota: na tabela ASCII da Wikipedia o caractere é apresentado na coluna "Glifo".

Comment: Muito boa explicação, obrigada :D

Comment: Apenas complementando: o C não necessariamente usa a tabela ASCII. Sendo assim o `48` nem sempre é `'0'`, mas `'0'` é sempre `'0'`. Então prefira escrever `data[i] - '0'`.

Comment: Outro ponto a se ressaltar é que isso funciona porque quem criou a tabela ASCII teve a sensibilidade de deixar os caracteres numéricos em ordem. Senão a conversão teria de ser na base do switch-case. Além disso, sempre é bom chegar se o caracter está entre '0' e '9' antes de fazer a conversão, só para ter certeza.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser No C os caracteres `'0'` a `'9'` sempre estão em ordem, independente de se é usado o ASCII ou não. Pelo standard (sessão 5.2.1/3): "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Comment: Foi isso que eu quis dizer. Falei da tabela ASCII apenas por ser a mais básica e conhecida.

Answer (score 3):

Caracteres em C são codificados em inteiros de acordo com o padrão ASCII^1. Como o Victor apontou na [responsta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3760/o-que-acontece-em-uma-conversao-de-um-char-para-um-int/3761#3761), os códigos ascii dos caracteres numéricos são consecutivos, começando com 48 para o zero. Por isso, subtraindo 48 transformamos o código do `'0'` em `0`, o código do `'1'` em `1`, etc.

Dito isso, eu não  escreveria esse código usando o 48 escrito na mão assim. Em primeiro lugar, você pode escrever `'0'` ao invés de 48 para deixar a intenção do código mais clara:

```
num[j]=data[i] - '0';
```

Em segundo lugar, a biblioteca padrão de C já tem funções para converter strings em números. Usando elas o seu código fica mais simples e robusto. Por exemplo, seu código atual vai ler errado se o dia ou mês tiver um dígito só ao invés de dois, você não testa para ver se os dígitos realmente são números, etc.

```
if(3 != sscanf("%d/%d/%d", data, dia, mes, ano)){
  /*tratar erro*/
}
```

---

^1 - Na maioria das implementações. Tecnicamente, o padrão permite outros encodings, como EBDIC

Comment: +1 Bacana a sugestão de deixar mais claro com o uso de '0'. :)

Answer (score 2):

Eis a parte relevante da tabela ASCII:

```
Código     Caractere
48         0
49         1
50         2
51         3
52         4
53         5
54         6
55         7
56         8
57         9
```

Então, ao pegar o caractere e subtrair 48, você está convertendo de caractere para número. Ao somar 48 você faz o contrário.