# Como converter um char para um inteiro?

Tags: c, conversão-de-tipo, char

Converter uma `string` para um inteiro com a função `atoi()` é fácil, não é mesmo?

Porém, quando eu uso a função `atoi()` para converter um caractere para um inteiro o programa que está em tempo de execução simplesmente acaba travando.

Qual seria a melhor forma para transformar um caractere (ex: '1') em um inteiro (ex: 1)?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3760/o-que-acontece-em-uma-convers%C3%A3o-de-um-char-para-um-int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 char c = '1';
int a = c - '0';
```

Não esquece da subtração

Answer (score 8):

> Converter uma string para um inteiro com a função `atoi()` é fácil, não é mesmo?

Não, esta função é considerada problemática e não deveria ser usada.

Para o que deseja basta fazer:

```
caractere - '0'
```

onde `caractere` é a variável que tem o `char` que deseja converter.

Claro que seria bom você verificar se o caractere é um dígito antes, a não ser que possa garantir que seja.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c = '1';
    printf("%d", (c - '0') + 1); // + 1 só p/ mostrar que virou numérico mesmo e faz a soma
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oHMOCY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fgrincaz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Chat2Int.c).

Comment: existe alguma outra função maniero

Comment: Pronta não existe.

Answer (score 2):

A função strtol() pode resolver seu problema. Tente algo assim:

```
int num;                      \\Variável para armazenar o número em formato inteiro
char cNum[] = {0};            \\Variável para armazenar o número em formato de string
printf("Digite um numero: "); \\Pedindo o número ao usuário
scanf("%s%*c", cNum);         \\Armazenando número em forma de string. O "%*c" serve para não acabar salvando "" (nada)
num = strtol(cNum, NULL, 10); \\Transformando para número inteiro de base 10
printf("%i", num);            \\Mostrando na tela o número salvo.
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que dá para fazer assim:

```
char c = '1';
//se retornar -1 ele não é número
int v = (int) (c > 47 && c < 58) ? c - 48 : -1;
```